# Tensorflow: How to apply 1d convolutions feature/channel vise?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, convolution

I want to process multivariate times series with a shape of [points in time, # features]

My goal is to apply 1d convolutions (with its own filters) to each feature stream ([points in time, 1]) separately. I don't want to use the 2D Convolutions since those would apply the same filters over all feature streams.

I know that [tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/DepthwiseConv2D?hl=de) and [tf.keras.layers.SeparableConv2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/SeparableConv2D?hl=de) exist, but i'm not sure whether these are appropriate to solve the problem and if so how.

Is it possible to perform this operation without splitting up the input in # feature many inputs and applying covolutions on those?

Comment: I don't have an exact working solution just a thought: You could maybe write a lambda layer that splits input tensor feature-wise, apply 1D convolution that is available in Tensorflow, and then merge (stack) results back into a tensor.

Comment: @VojtechMolek Thank you for your input. This was my back up plan, but i hoped that there would be simpler/cleaner solution.

Comment: I belive there is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `Conv1D` function defined in Tensorflow ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D)) with the [`groups`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D#arguments) argument to define individual filters for each feature.

An example of this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 128
N_TIME_POINTS = 300
N_FEATURES = 25
N_FILTERS_PER_FEATURE = 4

x = tf.random.normal(input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, N_FEATURES, N_TIME_POINTS))
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
    filters=N_FILTERS_PER_FEATURE*N_FEATURES,
    kernel_size=3,      # How many temporal samples fit into each filter
    activation='relu',
    padding='causal',
    groups=N_FEATURES,  # Important! treat each feature as a separate input
    input_shape=x.shape[1:])(x)
```

Note the importance on choosing the type of `padding` (see [padding documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D#arguments) for more info).

Comment: Again, you get the best answers if you post the wrong solution in the first place ;) Thanks, didn't know this argument existed.

Comment: I was planning to answer anyway :) Conv1D is a cool thing to use on many 1D signal processing tasks (Audio, stock options, temperature, ...)

Comment: As stated in other places, this can be seen a specific case of a grouped convolution where the number of groups is equal to the number of input channels (though people usually think of this as a way of speeding up computation, as in the case of depthwise convolution).

Answer (score 0):

I used the approach of manually spliting the streams:

```
input_shape = (self.hyper.time_series_length, self.hyper.time_series_depth, 1)
full_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
outputs = []

# Split the input tensors along the feature dimension, so 1D convolutions can be applied feature wise
feature_splits = tf.unstack(full_input, num=self.hyper.time_series_depth, axis=2)

for feature_input in feature_splits:
    x = feature_input

    for num_filters, kernel_size, strides in zip(self.hyper.conv_filters,
                                                 self.hyper.conv_kernel_size,
                                                 self.hyper.conv_strides):
        # Because these can also be used for the 2d variant the values are stored in lists
        # so the first element needs to be retrieved
        kernel_size = kernel_size[0]
        strides = strides[0]

        x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=num_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides,
                                   padding='SAME', activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(x)

    outputs.append(x)

# Merge the encoder outputs for each feature back into a single tensor
output = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=2)(outputs)
```

Comment: This solution seems to significantly slower amd more memory-indensive than https://stackoverflow.com/a/64990902/9670056 given that there is a lot of bolierplate and repetition (double `for` loop in python, one `Conv1D` layer per feature as opposed to 1 single Conv1D layer, etc...)